# Allure Report with Playwright on GitHub Pages Missing Test History

Tags: github-actions, github-pages, playwright, allure

I'm looking to integrate Allure Report with Playwright for test reporting and aim to host these reports on GitHub Pages to maintain a history of our tests. To achieve this, I've utilized the GitHub Marketplace action available at Allure Report with History. However, I'm encountering a consistent issue where the history section within my reports remains blank. My project is structured with backstage-showcase as the root directory, and e2e-tests as the subdirectory for my Playwright/Allure test scripts.

Below is the GitHub Actions configuration I'm using:

```
name: Playwright Tests
on:
  push:
    branches: [gh-actions, master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [gh-actions, master]
jobs:
  playwright:
    name: 'Playwright Tests'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        if: always()
        continue-on-error: true
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 18
      - name: Install dependencies (npm ci or npm install)
        run: |
          if [ ${{ steps.check-lock-file.outputs.exists }} == "true" ]; then
            npm ci
          else
            echo "package-lock.json not found, running npm install instead"
            npm install
          fi
        working-directory: ./e2e-tests
      - name: Run your tests
        run: npx playwright test
        working-directory: ./e2e-tests
        continue-on-error: true

      - name: Get Allure history
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        if: always()
        continue-on-error: true
        with:
          ref: gh-pages
          path: gh-pages

      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@master
        with:
          name: allure-results
          path: e2e-tests/allure-results
          retention-days: 20

      - name: Allure Report with history
        uses: simple-elf/allure-report-action@v1.8
        if: always()
        with:
          allure_results: e2e-tests/allure-results
          gh_pages: gh-pages
          allure_report: e2e-tests/allure-report
          allure_history: e2e-tests/allure-history
      - name: Deploy report to Github Pages
        if: always()
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        env:
          PERSONAL_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          PUBLISH_BRANCH: gh-pages
          PUBLISH_DIR: ./e2e-tests/allure-history
          keep_files: true
      - name: Post
```

While the Allure Report successfully publishes to GitHub Pages, its history functionality doesn't seem to work as expected. I ensure commits to a dedicated gh-actions branch I've created for this purpose.